# Adding delay in data acquisition in labview

Tags: signal-processing, delay, labview, data-acquisition

(Sorry I was not able to post picture as my reputation level is below 10)

What I wanted to do is, I want my laser displacement daq to start acquiring data after one second after the another daq acquisition  starts acquiring data.

I am not able to add delay  on the laser displacement daq.
(Both method should run for 10 second and laser displacement daq should be 1 second late at acquiring data.)

Thanks

Comment: Please upload the screenshot of your code to google drive or dropbox and provide the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to do that. Here are two ideas:

1. Acquire 11 seconds of data for both, and throw away the first 1 second of data from the laser.
2. Use the [Time Delay Express VI](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361M-01/lvexpress/time_delay/) and wires to control the order of code execution, as suggested by @nekomatic: [image] (Note: My original code, which uses Sequence Structures and the Wait (ms) Function, is at https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pIwb.png)

Comment: If you instead use the `Time Delay` Express VI, you don't need a sequence structure, because you can wire the error out from the DAQmx Timing vi to the error in of Time Delay, and the error out from Time Delay to error in of DAQmx Start Task. Using the error wire to control the order of execution like this is standard practice and good style in LabVIEW. http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvexpress/time_delay/

Comment: In my opinion correct timing is not guaranteed by your block diagram. The lower part of the code and the upper one are independent from each other. Strictly speaking the lower part (the one with the delay) could be executed until the "Task stop" VI even before the upper one starts the task.

Comment: Technically this is true, although unlikely on any modern PC. If you want to guarantee synchronisation (to +/- 1 sample), take JKSH's first suggestion and acquire from both channels in one operation and ignore the data you don't need.

Comment: Thanks for your input, nekomatic and MisterEmme. I've updated my code to use Time Delay and stricter sequencing using the error wires.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using **DAQmx Trigger Start Delay Property Node**.

[Here](http://www.ni.com/example/25905/en/) you can find a full example.

And [here](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/3615/en/) a nice tutorial from National Instruments on Task synchronization.